# How to access (Xpath) value of a role under parent in Chrome downloads

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Please refer to attached print, I want to access - value attribute under role = progress.

How can i get the Xpath of it ?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this other question if your goal to get the status of each download: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263317

Comment: Given one particular source document, finding an XPath to select a particular node is both trivially easy and useless (if you know what's in the document then you don't need to look). The reason you want an XPath expression is presumably because the document might be a bit different from this: and to find a suitable XPath expression, we need to know how the document might differ from the one shown.

Answer (score 1):

The xpath you need is:

```
//paper-progress[@role='progressbar']
```

Hit F12 in chrome, go to Console tab and typ:

```
$x("//paper-progress[@role='progressbar']")
```

Do this once the page is loaded properly and see if you get an element back.

Comment: I don't see how this could work since the targeted element is in a shadow-root. Do you get a result your console?