# How do I rename a file programmatically when it is downloaded automatically in Python-Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, listener, file-rename, python-watchdog

I have a Selenium(Chrome) script that goes to a URL and downloads a bunch of files sequentially. But the names are all gibberish and as such neither Selenium nor Chrome has control over the name of the downloaded file. So what I want to do is watch the download directory for any new files that are created and then rename them on creation with a name of my own choosing.

How do I go about this? I've heard that `watchdog` is a good package to create and log an EventListener. But then how do I dynamically pass the handler a particular name when the `on_created` event is triggered? Is **watchdog** the right way to go or is there some other solution that can work?

NOTE: I did try grabbing all the in the directory using `glob` and then update the name of the latest file by comparing the *creation time* but that results in a logical error as it mixes up the filenames in case the new file hasn't downloaded by the time this method is executed. I've attached the code below for this method.

```py
def __rename_downloaded_file(self, filename: str):
    """Rename the latest download file to the given name"""
    # TODO create a listener instead of the while loop
    while True:
        # keep looping in case there are no file in directory.
        list_of_files = glob.glob(f"{self.download_path}\\*.pdf")
        if len(list_of_files) > 0:
            break
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    print(latest_file)
    head, _ = os.path.split(latest_file)
    new_filename = os.path.join(head, filename+'.pdf')
    print(new_filename)
    os.rename(latest_file, new_filename)
```

Comment: How are you downloading the files? Consider using wget, which has the option of naming output files.

Comment: @agastya I am downloading the files automatically by clicking on buttons in the selenium script. I do not have the option of using `wget`.

Comment: Can you share the code used to run selenium and download files?

Comment: @agastya I can't. It'll give away the website that I'm scraping and it's proprietary. But I can tell you it's all through button clicks. So `self.driver.get_element_by_xpath(XPATH).click()`. A progress bar comes up(getting the file ready for export) and I wait for completion and then click the download link and the PDF pops up in the download section.

Comment: When you reach the last step (the download link appearing), use selenium to get the path of the link (it will be an <a> [href] link). Then use wget on that. It should work, and you will be able to rename the download.

Comment: I tried that. Getting a `403 Forbidden`. Tried with the `requests` library also didn't work. Not accepting the standard ca certificates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60677334/12085279).

@Raghavendra Phayde thank you for putting me on this thread.

The list of downloads you get is sorted by latest download timestamp. You can then rename each file with the below code.

```py
for old_filename, new_filename in zip(downloaded_file_names, rename_list):
    head, _ = os.path.split(old_filename)
    new_file_name_path = os.path.join(head, new_filename + '.pdf')
    # print(old_filename)
    # print(new_file_name_path)
    # print('\n')
    os.rename(old_filename, new_file_name_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

did u tried to wait for file to download. If u did that way, u can just  get latest file by  max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)  and changed the latest file name. After the file changed you could have started downloading other files

Comment: I can wait but for how long? Depends on the speed and stability of internet connection and yes I will be hosting this on a server at some point in the future and so i'll have a stable network then but until then what do I do? Some files are big while others are small. So can't have a hardcoded waiting time.

Comment: Check this [Wait for download to complete in selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263317/selenium-python-waiting-for-a-download-process-to-complete-using-chrome-web?rq=1) thread

Comment: thank you. This might work. I'll try it out and let you know.